# Trying to setup a Django app using gunicorn and systemd

Tags: ubuntu, django, systemd, gunicorn

Trying to setup a Django app using Gunicorn and Systemd while following [this tutorial by DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04).

When I run `curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock localhost`, it returns with `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`. I've followed the instructions to a T and even reset my VPS to make sure I didn't mess up the venv.

Anyone have any suggestions? All the other steps work fine, even connecting from the outside.

Comment: Do what the tutorial says to do if you have problems with this step.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've followed it to a T, as i said above

Comment: You haven't done anything that you have actually said in your question! The tutorial shows several things you should do if `curl` returns an error. Have you done them yet? What was the result?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've just actually figured out why it didn't work. I forgot to change the paths and user to my own user. Thanks for a little slap, tore my hair out for a few minutes.

Comment: @mystlegend, can you elaborate how you fixed this for the rest of us?